# Divisor proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry

I was asked by my professor to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra using the fact that for any function defined on the projective plane $deg(div(f))=0$. Now if we let $p(x,z)=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^iz^{n-i}}{z^n}, a_i\in\mathbb{K}$ then every polynomial has a pole at the point of order $n$ at infinity $(x,z)=(1,0)$ and thus it must have $n$ roots.

The thing is this proof does not require $\mathbb{K}$ to be algebraically closed. So this would imply that for example in $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})$ every polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots. Could someone please explain to me where is the mistake?

Comment: What is your definition of $div(f)$ over a field that is not necessarily algebraically closed?  If it is just the thing you get by adding up the roots and poles (in the base field) then $deg(div(f))=0$ is not true in general.

Comment: Yes my definition is that given a divisor $D=\sum{n_P(P)}$ then $deg(D)=\sum{n_P}$

Comment: So you are saying that $deg(div(f))=0$ only holds in the closure $\bar{K}$?

Comment: Which $P$ are you summing over?  If $\mathbb{K}$ is not algebraically closed, the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{K}[x]$ (or similarly for Proj) are basically Galois orbits.  Either you sum over all Galois orbits, in which case the mistake is in assuming Galois orbits are singletons, or you only sum over $\mathbb{K}$-points, in which case you didn't sum all the zeros to make $\operatorname{deg}(\operatorname{div}(f))=0$.

Comment: You are correct I was summing over $\mathbb{K}$-points so the sum is not $0$... it seems so clear now